# Openssl speed test for Broadcom engine

Tags: linux, performance, ssl, cryptography, openssl

I'm using OpenSSL 1.0.1e.

The OpenSSL engine ubsec, requires additional library containing the actual implementation.
The implementation library is /usr/lib/libvendor_ubsec.so.

To instruct from ubsec OpenSSL engine what implementation to load we use from code:

```
ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string (&engine, "SO_PATH", vendor_ubsec, 0);
```

I want to run openssl speed test as following:

```
openssl speed rsa1024 -engine ubsec
```

But it fails, since openssl doesn't load libvendor_ubsec.so.

I understand that this related to OpenSSL *dynamic* engines and to load implementation I need to use something like:

openssl engine ubsec -pre SO_PATH:vendor_ubsec

My question how I "combine" two comamnd **openssl speed** and **openssl engine** to run speed test for ubsec engine>

Comment: That's a pretty specific question; the only thing I can do is upvote. Have you tried contacting the vendor? If you have an answer, please report back...

Comment: @owlstead Of course I'll update then question If I'll know something. Anyway, I thing the question is ENGINE agnostic :)

Comment: OpenSSL has a default location it likes to load engines from. For example, on Fedora it's `/usr/lib64/openssl/engine`. Have you tried symlinking your libvendor_ubsec.so into that directory and then using the `openssl speed rsa1024 -engine ubsec` command? Alternately you can drop into the OpenSSL command line, load the engine, then execute the speed test with the engine parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Use the openssl command interpreter interactively instead of sending in single commands, that way, in the same execution context, you can load the engine and then run the commands. This [site](http://grid.ncsa.illinois.edu/myproxy/ca/engine/) also has useful information on defining the library load paths

```
gmurphy@interloper:~$ openssl
OpenSSL> engine dynamic
(dynamic) Dynamic engine loading support
OpenSSL> speed rsa1024                                   
Doing 1024 bit private rsa's for 10s: 32226 1024 bit private RSA's in 9.96s
Doing 1024 bit public rsa's for 10s: 542409 1024 bit public RSA's in 9.96s
```